# Webix - Rest Mode Support - Datatable - Set ID column for CRUD operation

Tags: entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api, webix

I'm following [these instructions](http://docs.webix.com/desktop__server_rest.html), and adapted [this example](http://docs.webix.com/samples/40_serverside/03_php_custom/02_datatable_saving_rest.html).
The problem is that my data **ID** isn't named **ID**.
So when I tried to change the data, the **ID** sent to my REST API is some crazy number.

Is there a way to configure which datatable column or field from my JSON will be used as ID?

**OR**
Will I need to change the name returned from my REST API and how the best way to do this without changing the structure of the database?

**JSON Output:**

```
[
    {
        "nu_unidade": "sample string 2", 
        "nome": "sample string 4", 
    },{
        "nu_unidade": "sample string 2", 
        "nome": "sample string 4", 
    },{
        "nu_unidade": "sample string 2", 
        "nome": "sample string 4",
    }
]
```

**ASP Net Model:**

```
namespace Site.Models {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    public partial class Unidade {
        public string nu_unidade { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Using:**

- Webix 4.2
- .Net Framework 4.0
- Web API 1.0
- EF 5.0

Comment: what does your model look like?

Comment: JSON output look like:
`[
  {
    "nu_unidade": "sample string 2",
    "nome": "sample string 4",
  },
  {
    "nu_unidade": "sample string 2",
    "nome": "sample string 4",
  },
  {
    "nu_unidade": "sample string 2",
    "nome": "sample string 4",
  }
]`
My ASP NET Model:
`namespace Site.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Unidade
    {
        public string nu_unidade { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
    }
}`

Comment: You should include that in your question as an edit.  Be sure to format as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pretty sure Webix can't work without an "id" field (It automatically create a one with random big interger). If your API can't send it, maybe you could try to map data in webix datatable : http://docs.webix.com/datatable__data_mapping.html

```
columns:[
    { 
        id:"id",  
        map:"#nu_unidade#", 
        header:"Id" 
    }
],
```

Or you could force id at data initialization :

```
scheme: {
   $init:function(obj){
       obj.id = obj.nu_unidade;
     } 
}
```

Comment: Tried your second suggestion (Data Initialization) and worked as intended.

Comment: One more thing: Using any of the above ways result in breaking the sort functionality of the datatable: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`